# Resize the View inside a UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uitoolbar

I have a `UIViewController` in a Storyboard app.

[image]

The Navigation bar is automatically added when a segue is set and I've added a `UIToolBar` from the IB to the bottom.

At runtime a `UIScrollView` is added to the view controller as the view. The problem that caused was it overlaps the `UIToolBar` which was added before. So I added the following line and pulled back the tool bar to the front.

```
self.mailOptionsToolbar.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Now it appears fine but there's still a small issue. When I click on the tool bar button item in the `UIToolBar`, they just don't work. Say, in the scroll view if there's UITextbox placed right underneath any of those buttons, when I click them it pops up the keyboard! Its like the click is falling through the `UIToolBar` to the UITextField below. How can I stop this from happening?

I was think of another way too. That is resizing the `UIScrollBar` to fit only the white spaced area so that it won't cover up the `UIToolBar` in the first place thus not spawning this clicking issue. But I don't know how to make the `UIScrollView` which is added at runtime to be fit only within the white area.

Suggestions to both of these will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    // 20.0f is for status bar height and 44.0f is for navigation bar
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = screenHeight - 20.0f - 44.0f - self.mailOptionsToolbar.frame.size.height;
    CGRect frame = [CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, scrollViewHeight)];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```